# java - stored procedure db link

Tags: java, spring, oracle, database-performance

I have two databases in Oracle both are on different servers.

When i am calling web service it connect to Database 1 it will fetch data from Database 2 which is on remote server. We have used DB link for now to get data from remote server and for web service implementation Spring was used. But we are getting performance issue because of DB link.

So is there any option or alternative from Java side to get data from other server and call Stored Procedure from server 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Materialized View in Database1 populated with data in Database2 via DBLink. This will eliminate the incidental performance issue from the live DBLink query, but will introduce a data latency issue between matview refreshes.

docs: [Oracle Materialized Views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have no idea on db side but i like to handle it from java

Comment: Ah, misread it as "alternatives _to_ java".  Do you have credentials to  connect directly to database2?  You could use a [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).  Alternatively, have you ever heard of YADA? http://github.com/Novartis/YADA  is a instant web-api for JDBC datasources

Comment: no, that is on clients's machine but my stored procedure is on Server1 and data tables are on Server2. So what happens when application is loaded spring creates database connection. so i am targetting data base 1. I am calling stored procedure of Server 1 but queries inside Stored Procedure will fetch data from Server 2 which is at remote destination. So because of this we are getting perfomance issue

Comment: If you can't connect java to server2 i think your options might be limited to some kind of caching strategy. if not the materialized view in the db, can you preload/stage/cache the server2 data by calling the service/stored proc ahead of time?

Comment: No all queries are dynamic

Comment: I want to do something like a continues connection between two servers using java and i transfer a n no of object like Pojo or json object on that connection and execute over there.But i am confused is it possible using Socket programming or any other way?